# Freebase - AUTHOR search "influenced_by"

Tags: api, freebase

I'm trying to search Google Freebase for Authors who were influenced by another Author.
For instance:  "Who influenced Stephen King?"

I currently have the MQL working, But I cannot figure out how to do it with the Search API.

The MQL is as follows...

```
  [{
  "type": "/book/author",
  "name": "Stephen King",
  "/influence/influence_node/influenced_by": [{
    "name": null
  }]
}]
```

How does this translate into the Search API?

I have tried the following...

```
String serviceURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search";
String query = "Stephen King";
String filter = "(all type:/book/author type:/influence/influence_node/influenced_by)";
```

But this returns nothing.

Help!

Comment: One issue is that `/influence/influence_node/influenced_by` is a property, not a type.  The owning type is `/influence/influence_node`.  There should be a way to do this in the Search API using the metaschema so that you could do things like find all authors influenced by something born within 100 km of Paris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I always find the answer right after I post the question!

The answer is to use the **Topic API**.

The code to create the URL is as follows...

```
String topicId = "/en/stephen_king";
String filter = "/influence/influence_node";
String serviceURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic" + topicId;
```

Querying the "influence_node" brings back data for two properties:

- influenced
- influenced_by

Thus by running just this one query, I can get back two separate sets of data.

If I only wanted "influenced_by" data, the filter would be...

```
String filter = "/influence/influence_node/influenced_by";
```

I hope this helps someone!